# Get TinyMCE textcontent in AngularJS controller

Tags: angularjs, tinymce, angular-ui

I'm beggining with angularJS and what I want is to submit a form with an tinymce-ui textarea and submit both the HTML content and text content.

For now I have the tinyMce textarea working.

> ```
>    <div>
>     <form method="post">
>     <textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" ng-model="user.commentaireValue" id="tinymce1"></textarea>
>             <textarea>{{user.commentaireValue}}</textarea>
>             <textarea id="IwouldLikeNonHtmlContent">{{HELPME}}</textarea>
>         </form>
>     </div>
> ```

If I type in the console

> ```
>    tinyMCE.get('tinymce1').getBody().textContent
> ```

I get what I want.
I just can't figure out how to retrieve it in my controller

> ```
>    app.controller('UserCreationCtrl', ['$scope', 'UsersFactory', '$location',
>      function ($scope, UsersFactory, $location) {
>     // callback for ng-click 'createNewUser':
>     $scope.createNewUser = function () {
>         UsersFactory.create($scope.user);
>         $location.path('/user-list');
>     };
>     $scope.options=[
>         {name:'black', shade:'dark'},
>         {name:'white', shade:'light'},
>         {name:'red', shade:'dark'},
>         {name:'blue', shade:'dark'},
>         {name:'yellow', shade:'light'}
>     ];
>     $scope.correctlySelected = $scope.options[1];
>     $scope.tinymceOptions = {
>         resize: false,
>         width: 400,  // I *think* its a number and not '400' string
>         height: 300,
>         plugins: 'textcolor link',
>         toolbar: "undo redo styleselect bold italic forecolor backcolor",
>         menu : { // this is the complete default configuration
>             edit   : {title : 'Edit'  , items : 'undo redo | cut copy paste pastetext | selectall'},
>             insert : {title : 'Insert', items : 'link media | template hr'},
>             format : {title : 'Format', items : 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | formats | removeformat'},
>         }
>     };
>     //tinyMCE.get('tinymce1').getBody().textContent;
> }]);
> ```

How can I do that without using sanitize function ?
Thnak you.

Comment: it is bound to `$scope.user.commentaireValue` by the  `ng-model` you set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `init_instance_callback` to attach event listeners for `KeyUp`, `ExecCommand` and `SetContent` within the active tinymce `editor` and bind a `$scope` variable whenever these events are triggered. If you check the `ui-tinymce` directive source code you will see that these events are used to update the model.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$scope.tinymceOptions = {
        resize: false,
        width: 400,  // I *think* its a number and not '400' string
        height: 300,
        plugins: 'textcolor link',
        toolbar: "undo redo styleselect bold italic forecolor backcolor",
        menu : { // this is the complete default configuration
            edit   : {title : 'Edit'  , items : 'undo redo | cut copy paste pastetext | selectall'},
            insert : {title : 'Insert', items : 'link media | template hr'},
            format : {title : 'Format', items : 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | formats | removeformat'},
        },

        init_instance_callback: function(editor) {
          var textContentTrigger = function() {
            $scope.textContent = editor.getBody().textContent;
            $scope.$apply();
          };

          editor.on('KeyUp', textContentTrigger);
          editor.on('ExecCommand', textContentTrigger);
          editor.on('SetContent', function(e) {
            if(!e.initial)
              textContentTrigger();
          });
        }
    };
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea>{{textContent}}</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works like a charm :) Just in case it could help someone I was looking for editor.getContent({format : 'text'}); in order to retrieve line breaks with raw text.